# SpringBoot do not scan named packages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, component-scan

I build a demo module based on SpringBoot , and include server and client application.
The path like:

```
├── test
│   ├── client
│   │   ├── DemoController.java
│   │   └── ClientApplication.java
│   ├── server
│   │   └── ServerApplication.java
```

I wrote two conflicting custom annotation `@Client` and `@Server` presented on `ClientApplication.java` and `ServerApplication.java`.

When I run client or server, the two annotations conflicted.

I want to run ClientApplication without scan package `test.server`, also for ServerApplication.

I have tried something but not work(springBootVersion = '1.5.11.RELEASE'):

```
@Client
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "test.client", excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "test\\.server\\.*"),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, pattern = ServerApplication.class)
})
public class ClientApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args).stop();
    }
}
```

---

I wrote the wrong code in ClientApplication.main:

`SpringApplication.run(***ServerApplication***.class, args).stop();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For server:

```
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = "test.server", excludeFilters = {
    @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "test.client.*")})
```

For client:

```
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = "test.client", excludeFilters = {
    @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "test.server.*")})
```

Or exclude class using specific filter:

```
 @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = ServerApplication.class)
```

Comment: @ajianzheng try exclude class using specific filter:  `@Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = ServerApplication.class)`

Comment: sorry, you are right, i wrote the wrong code. thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It looks quite strange as the two applications are not in the same base package. The configuration class from other package should not have been discovered even without explicit exclusion.

Anyway how about trying this:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "test.client", 
  excludeFilters = @Filter(type=FilterType.REGEX, pattern="test\\.server\\.*"))
```

Furthermore you can try using @Profile annotation to split the classes into client and server profiles.

Comment: It's a demo, i don't wanna build two module just for example, and i am interested in this problem.